# struts :404 status The request resource not found

Tags: struts2, myeclipse

i am writing my first struts example .i followed the exact steps but even then facing this problem,dont know whats wrong code was working on my teacher's machine but on mine not ,i think there is a small mistake i am doing plz help me to locate
1) i have index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<s:form action="login">
<s:textfield name="username" label="username:"></s:textfield>
<s:submit></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

2) the bean package with Loginaction class(pogo class)

```
package bean;

public class Loginaction {
    String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String execute()
    {


            return "success";


    }



}
```

3) the struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="demo" extends="struts-default">
<action name="login" class="bean.Loginaction">
<result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>

</action>
</package>

</struts>
```

4) the welcome.jsp

```
<h1>hi user.</h1>
```

5) the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>struts1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

6) and the directory structure

both package and the struts.xml in the src folder and else in the web-inf (jsps and the web.xml)

on the console i am getting``

```
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home/tarun/MyEclipse Blue/binary/com.sun.java.jdk.linux.x86_64_1.6.0.u43/bin:/home/tarun/MyEclipse Blue/plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.easie.tomcat.myeclipse_11.0.0.me201211151802/tomcat/bin
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:26 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1059)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
SEVERE: Catalina.start
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 379 ms
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.13
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:29 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:29 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:501)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3506 ms
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:590)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:29 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080`enter code here`
Apr 4, 2013 12:54:29 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector pause
SEVERE: Protocol handler pause failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkMain.pause(JkMain.java:679)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.pause(JkCoyoteHandler.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.pause(Connector.java:1074)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:659)
```

Comment: `java.net.BindException: Address already in use:8080`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that a process is already using port 8080.  Commonly, newbies are tripped up by starting a tomcat instance without having shutdown the previous one.  You should check that.  Also, it's possible that there was already another service listening on port 8080. If so, you need to identify what process is using port 8080.

My advice is that you learn what tools are available on your system that will help you answer the following questions:

1) what processes are running?

2) Which ones have network ports open for listening to incoming requests, aka which ones are servers?

Once you can do this, you'll know how to identify the conflicting process and then you just need to go shut it down.

Comment: The user may have several servers defined in MyEclipse and already have one running when trying to use another. Look in the Servers view and stop all servers before trying to run the application on a MyEclipse server from the project context menu. Alternatively, he may have another instance, external to MyEclipse, running and, if so, this needs to be shut down. Logging off the system and logging on again should clear all those.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing all the tomcat and Java processes on the machine you saw the error and try starting tomcat again. In your case 8080 is already being used by another process. Kill that first and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the tomcat server http port nb in the **server.xml** file remaining keep as it is.

to do that follow the below steps:

1. open **../tomcat5.x/conf/server.xml** and change the port nb such like **8081** or 8090 any instead of 8080
   In...
   `<---Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080---->`
   `<Connector port="8090" ..........>`
2. Save it.
3. finally start the tomcat server

thats all.
thank you.

raam